# Moose: Extending Exporter causes constructor to disappear?

Tags: perl, moose, exporter

Here's something weird that I can't figure out. I have a Moose class that I also want to export some constants, using the age-old standard Exporter module. However, as soon as I add `extends Exporter` to my class, for some reason, the default Moose constructor no longer gets inherited and I get the fatal error:

```
Can't locate object method "new" via package "MyApp::Dispatch"
```

Here is a simple test which demonstrates the problem.

```
package Foo;
use Moose;
use constant NARF => 'poit';
extends 'Exporter';

1;

$ perl -I./lib -MFoo -e '$f=Foo->new'
Can't locate object method "new" via package "Foo" at -e line 1.
```

Removing the `extends` line makes the problem vanish.

This is using Moose 0.93.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is assuming you are inheriting from another Moose-based class, so it doesn't inherit from Moose::Object.  I'm not sure what the standard answer would be: just manually adding Moose::Object or somehow using MooseX::NonMoose or something else.

But Exporter works just fine even when not inherited; just import its import routine:

```
use Exporter "import";
```

Comment: Well, that should have been obvious, shouldn't it? I feel dumb tonight. :) I've even used MooseX::NonMoose before, so I should have thought of that, but didn't. Anyway, importing `import` rather than inheriting works fine.

Comment: Moose's `extends` is equivalent to `@ISA = @list`. If this list is empty at compile time Moose will automatically put `Moose::Object` into @ISA for you.

Comment: @perigrin: that was basically what I said.

Answer (score 2):

You already got the real answer, but the real *question* is why do you have a module that exports stuff and is an object? That's a pretty weird design, and may be a code smell.

Comment: The exports are constants which are used by callbacks registered by other parts of the system; I agree it's a little weird and will probably end up rethinking the design sooner or later. But it works for now.